# Discord JS // Trying to add role & remove roles by reacting to the message

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am trying to code a role reaction for my discord bot. Currently, right now I am stuck on how to make it so multiple people can react to the message to receive a role(s) or remove role(s). I would also like the embed message to be a constant message.

Any guidance would be helpful as I have been trying to code this for several days and I just cant get it.

This is my current code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const colors = require("../colors");
const botconfig = require("../botconfig")

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {


    const eRole = message.guild.roles.get('688477690344374283'); // Events
    const uRole = message.guild.roles.get('688477558982836344'); // Updates
    const pRole = message.guild.roles.get('688477868078137369'); // Polls
    const smRole = message.guild.roles.get('687498488295981069'); // Social Media
    const qRole = message.guild.roles.get('688477467840872452'); // QOTD

   const filter = (reaction, user) => ['❤️', '', '', '',''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;

  let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setTitle('Pinged Roles')
        .setDescription(`

      ❤️ ${eRole.toString()}
       ${uRole.toString()}
       ${pRole.toString()}
       ${smRole.toString()}
       ${qRole.toString()}
        `)
        .addField("**TIP:**", "Double react to remove a role")
        .setColor(colors.aqua)
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter(`mc.advancius.net`,bot.user.displayAvatarURL)

    message.channel.send(embed).then(async msg => {

        await msg.react('❤️');
        await msg.react('');
        await msg.react('');
        await msg.react('');
        await msg.react('');

      msg.awaitReactions(filter, {

        max:1,


        }).then(collected => {

            const reaction = collected.first();

            switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
                case '❤️':
                    if (message.member.roles.has(eRole.id)) {
                        return message.channel.send('You are already in this role!').then(m => m.delete(3000));
                    }
                    message.member.addRole(eRole).catch(err => {
                        console.log(err);
                        return message.channel.send(`Error adding you to this role: **${err.message}**.`);
                    });
                    message.channel.send(`You have been added to the **${eRole.name}** role!`).then(m => m.delete(3000));

                    break;
                case '':
                    if (message.member.roles.has(uRole.id)) {

                        return message.channel.send('You are already in this role!').then(m => m.delete(3000));
                    }
                    message.member.addRole(uRole).catch(err => {
                        console.log(err);
                        return message.channel.send(`Error adding you to this role: **${err.message}**.`);
                    });
                    message.channel.send(`You have been added to the **${uRole.name}** role!`).then(m => m.delete(3000));

                    break;
                case '':
                    if (message.member.roles.has(pRole.id)) {

                        return message.channel.send('You are already in this role!').then(m => m.delete(3000));
                    }
                    message.member.addRole(pRole).catch(err => {
                        console.log(err);
                        return message.channel.send(`Error adding you to this role: **${err.message}**.`);
                    });
                    message.channel.send(`You have been added to the **${pRole.name}** role!`).then(m => m.delete(3000));

                    break;
              case '':
                    if (message.member.roles.has(smRole.id)) {

                        return message.channel.send('You are already in this role!').then(m => m.delete(3000));
                    }
                    message.member.addRole(smRole).catch(err => {
                        console.log(err);
                        return message.channel.send(`Error adding you to this role: **${err.message}**.`);
                    });
                    message.channel.send(`You have been added to the **${smRole.name}** role!`).then(m => m.delete(3000));

                    break;
              case '':
                    if (message.member.roles.has(qRole.id)) {
                        return message.channel.send('You are already in this role!').then(m => m.delete(3000));
                    }
                    message.member.addRole(qRole).catch(err => {
                        console.log(err);
                        return message.channel.send(`Error adding you to this role: **${err.message}**.`);
                    });
                    message.channel.send(`You have been added to the **${qRole.name}** role!`).then(m => m.delete(3000));

                    break;
          };
      });
  })             
};

exports.help = {
    name: 'roles2'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a collector, I would advise to save that message's object or ID to a JSON and, listen for `messageReactionAdd` and `messageReactionRemove` event to check the emoji used to add and remove role.

Example:

```js
bot.on("messageReactionAdd", (reaction, user) => {

     if (reaction.message.id != "stored_msg_id") return; // or you can compare the message objects

     const eRole = message.guild.roles.get('688477690344374283');
     switch (reaction.emoji.name) { 
          case "❤️": reaction.message.guild.member(user).addRole(eRole); break;
          // etc.
     }
});
```

Things might change depending on your version of discord.js version